# groovy convert from csv to json

Tags: groovy, groovyshell, groovy-console

How can I convert a CSV into JSON and access the objects individually for creating a custom string? In the following code why I cannot view the output of log.info(rows.Id[0]) ?????? When i print it shows me null in console.

data.csv has two columns (ID, Value) with 100 rows.

```groovy
import groovy.json.JsonOutput
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
def lines = new File('data.csv').readLines()

def keys = lines[0].split(',')
def rows = lines[1..-1].collect { line ->
def i = 0, vals = line.split(',')
        keys.inject([:]) { map, key -> map << ["$key": vals[i++]] }
    }

def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
jsonSlurper = jsonSlurper.parse(JsonOutput.toJson(rows))
log.info(JsonOutput.prettyPrint(JsonOutput.toJson(rows)))
log.info(rows.Id[0])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem here is the use of a GString as key in the map.  This
looks/prints like a string key, but in terms of identity (how the map
looks things up) it is not.

```
groovy:000> key = "a"
===> a
groovy:000> ["$key": 1].containsKey(key)
===> false
groovy:000> [(key): 1].containsKey(key)
===> true
```

So use: `[(key): vals[i++]]` instead.

Or if you want to golf this further:

```
[keys, line.split(',')].transpose().collectEntries()
```

Comment: javax.script.ScriptException: javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: groovy.json.JsonSlurper.parse() is applicable for argument types: (String) values:

Comment: I see this exception when i changed to [(key): vals[i++]] . My goal is to read csv and convert to json, so that i can manipulate few things(create a new string out of the values i capture) as per my requirement.

Comment: It's `parseText` not `parse`.  The error message most likely tells you that.

Comment: Ok, can you tell me why this code is returning nothing. It is the extension for above one.def foo= (int)Math.floor(rows.Id.size()/1000)
  def subList=rows.Id.subList(0, 1000)
  String str = subList.toString().join('-')
  println(str)
  def names_str = jsonSlurper.Id.getClass()

Comment: if you have different questions, please create a new question